# Hilbert space and a subspace

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Infinite dimensional function space known as a Hilbert space, denoted as $H$, and initialized with inner product $(\textbf u|\textbf v)$ is a space in which an operator $L$ (positive and summetric) acts. Another Hilbert space $H_L$ is defined with the inner product being $(L\textbf u|\textbf v)$. It is claimed that if the operator $L$ is *positive definite* over $H$ then $H_L$ is a subspace of $H$!
A proof of this postulate stems form the definition of positive definite operator:
$L$ is positive definite if there is a positive number $\gamma$ such that $(L\textbf u|\textbf u)\geq \gamma(\textbf u|\textbf u)$ for all $\textbf u$ in $H$. Then the following inequality pops out: $||\textbf u||^2=(\textbf u|\textbf u)\leq \frac{(L\textbf u|\textbf u)}{\gamma}=\frac {||\textbf u||_L^2}{\gamma}$ and it is stated that namely due to this inequality $H_L$ is a subspace of $H$!

So my question is why the last inequality means that $H_L$ is a subspace of $H$?

Also if $L$ is only positive but not positive definite then why we can't say that $H_L$ is a subspace of $H$?

Actually at the end it was written $H_L\subset H$ which I interpret as $H_L$ is a subspace of $H$ since earlier in the book it was written explicitly that $H_L$ is a space.

Comment: This seems to be using a weird definition of "subspace" of a Hilbert space. I (and I think most mathematicians) would require, as part of the definition of "subspace", that the inner product of any two vectors in the subspace is the same as the inner product of those same vectors as calculated in the original space.  In other words, the inner product functions should agree wherever both are defined.

Comment: Thanks for that comment I find it reasonable, indeed how could be that the subspace is defined with different inner product then its container that's also a question, weird!!!

Comment: I think the question should have been just to show that $H_L$ is a Hilbert space, not that it's a subspace of $H$. For that question, the inequality $\Vert u\Vert^2\leq\Vert u\Vert_L^2/\gamma$ is just what you need to show that, in $H_L$, the only vector with norm zero is the zero vector.  That's the Hilbert-space axiom that will fail if $L$ is allowed to have a nontrivial kernel; all vectors in the kernel will have $\Vert u\Vert_L=0$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass But what if $L$ is only positive operatot, i.e. $L(\textbf u,\textbf u)\geq \textbf 0$ for all $\textbf u$ whit equality only in the case $\textbf u=\textbf 0$? Does this mean that $H_L$ is again a space? I mean in the book it was emphasized that the operator $L$ should be positive-definite for sure. But in my opinion only positive operator also do the job!

Comment: As far as I know, "positive definite" means (for Hermitian operators) exactly that $L(u,u)\geq 0$ for all $u$ with equality only in the case $u=0$. Apparently your source uses a different definition; what is it?

Comment: @AndreasBlass The given definition distinguishes positive operator from positive-definite operator as follows:
1) $L$ is positive operator if $(L\textbf u|\textbf u)\geq 0$ for all $\textbf u$ in $H$ with equality only in the case $\textbf u=\textbf 0$;
2) $L$ is positive definite operator if there is a positive number $\gamma$ (same for all $\textbf u \in H$) such that $(L\textbf u|\textbf u)\geq \gamma(\textbf u|\textbf u)$ for all $\textbf u$ in $H$.
In this definition positive operator is something like bounded form bellow!

Comment: Thanks. Now I see what I missed in my previous comments: "Positive" suffices to ensure the axiom I mentioned, that $\Vert u\Vert_L$ is nonnegative and vanishes only when $u=0$, so that $\langle Lu,v\rangle$ is an inner product. But the stronger "positive definite" condition seems to be needed to ensure that $H_L$ is complete. Without  "definite" you could have sequences that are Cauchy with respect to $\Vert-\Vert_L$ but not with respect to the original norm $\Vert-\Vert$, and such a sequence would lack a limit in $H$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for all the comments it is clear now.